# Some public posts are missing in facebook graph api querying result

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched this topic for a while, but cannot find any workable solution.

The problem is that I am certainly sure there is a public post in a specific time interval, but it is missing in api response.

For example, a public post api querying url is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/179043295447791_1660881430597296/?access_token=your_token
```

and my querying url for a page is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/edn168/posts/?limit=100&since=2017-08-20&until=2017-08-25&access_token=your_token
```

As shown in data, two page ids are the same 179043295447791, and the created date of the missing post is 2017-08-23 which falls in the time interval. Why I cannot get the post?

Does anyone have any tips or suggestions?